# CAAnimation how to raise interpolation or redraw frequency

Tags: ios, iphone, core-animation, avfoundation

When animating the `position` or `bounds` of a `CALayer` with a `CAKeyframeAnimation` (or probably with any other `CAAnimation`) and exporting a full HD 1920x1080 or HDReady 1280x720 movie using `AVAssetExport`, the animation in the resulting movie become jumpy.

If the resolution is the same as the native iPhone screen size, the animation stays fluid.

`CAAction` seem to have no impact on the result. Using a `path` instead of `values` doesn't change anything either.

Here's a short [**short  video**](http://youtu.be/kWPvC7Agy9o) showing the issue.

My guess is I should need to interpolate more frequently or redraw more (or less) frequently the layer during the animation. Any idea to act on those parameters ?

The layer

```
CALayer * layer       = [CALayer layer];
layer.anchorPoint     = CGPointZero;
layer.frame           = self.creator.animationLayer.bounds;
layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
layer.opacity         = 0.f;
layer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspectFill;
layer.contents        = (__bridge id)image;
```

The Animation

```
CAKeyframeAnimation * contentRectAnimation =
[CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
contentRectAnimation.removedOnCompletion   = NO;
contentRectAnimation.beginTime             = beginTime;
contentRectAnimation.duration              = totalDuration;
contentRectAnimation.fillMode              = kCAFillModeBoth;
contentRectAnimation.keyTimes              = keyTimes;
contentRectAnimation.values                = positions;
contentRectAnimation.timingFunctions       = timingFunctions;

[self.currentAnimationLayer addAnimation:contentRectAnimation
                                  forKey:@"position"];

CAKeyframeAnimation * boundsAnimation =
[CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"bounds"];
boundsAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
boundsAnimation.beginTime           = beginTime;
boundsAnimation.duration            = totalDuration;
boundsAnimation.fillMode            = kCAFillModeBoth;
boundsAnimation.keyTimes            = keyTimes;
boundsAnimation.values              = bounds;
boundsAnimation.timingFunctions     = timingFunctions;

[self.currentAnimationLayer addAnimation:boundsAnimation
                                  forKey:@"bounds"];
```

Comment: You can slow down the layer (using the `speed` property) and capture  frames less frequently (but the same number of frames that you would expect your movie to contain

Comment: I'll try that thanks. But I wonder how it will interact with AVAssetsTracks speed when mixed with videos and exported

Comment: well if I slow down the layer speed then I have to raise the animation duration which give the same final result...

Comment: No, slowing down the layer makes the animation take longer to complete (without adjusting the duration)

Comment: sry I meant if layer speed is 0.5 then animduration has to be *0.5 too.I can make the animation take longer to avoid the jump but it's the user who decide the duration of the animation.